# how to detect touches on uisegmentedcontrol - even on selected segment?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

While detecting changes works with `UIControlEventValueChanged` - I need to detect touches even on selected segments.

I tried

```
   [onOffSC addTarget:self
            action:@selector(segmentedControlPushed)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
```

But this fires nothing.

**Is there a way to detect touches on a selected segment?**

EDIT - without having to create a new subclass. 
ps also the gesture recognizer does not accept the segmentcontrol when trying to drag it there

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSInteger oldValue = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if ( oldValue == self.selectedSegmentIndex )
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

Comment: for this I have to create a new subclass... - I forgot to mention it initially

Comment: You should be able to connect Tap Gesture Recognizer to SegmentedControl in IB, then just connect your own method - (IBAction)segmentedControlTouched:(id)sender. I'm pretty sure this method will fire everytime you touch SegmentedControl.

Comment: ..as I mentioned above, for some reason this does not work - possibly bec I am using Xcode 4.3????

Comment: See this answer for an iOS 7 updated version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17652998/292145