# How to deselect a segment in Segmented control button permanently till its clicked again

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` with 4 segments. When it is selected, it should maintain the `selected state`. When the same segment is clicked again, it should `deselect itself`.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Since `UISegmentedControl` only sends an action if a not selected segment is selected, you have to subclass `UISegmentedControl` to make a tiny change in its touch handling. I use this class:

```
@implementation MBSegmentedControl

// this sends a value changed event even if we reselect the currently selected segment
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSInteger current = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if (current == self.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
}

@end
```

Now you will get `UIControlEventValueChanged` events even if the segment is already selected. Simply save the current index in a variable and compare it in the action. If the two indexes match you have to unselect the touched segment.

```
// _selectedSegmentIndex is an instance variable of the view controller

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    _selectedSegmentIndex = self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex;
}

- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == _selectedSegmentIndex) {
        NSLog(@"Segment %d deselected", sender.selectedSegmentIndex);
        sender.selectedSegmentIndex =  UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
        _selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Segment %d selected", sender.selectedSegmentIndex);
        _selectedSegmentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
    }
}
```

---

iOS 7 changed how touches are handled for UISegmentedControl. The selectedSegmentIndex is now changed during `touchesEnded:`.

So the updated Subclass should look like this:

```
@implementation MBSegmentedControl

+ (BOOL)isIOS7 {
    static BOOL isIOS7 = NO;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSInteger deviceSystemMajorVersion = [[[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
        if (deviceSystemMajorVersion >= 7) {
            isIOS7 = YES;
        }
        else {
            isIOS7 = NO;
        }
    });
    return isIOS7;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSInteger previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if (![[self class] isIOS7]) {
        // before iOS7 the segment is selected in touchesBegan
        if (previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            // if the selectedSegmentIndex before the selection process is equal to the selectedSegmentIndex
            // after the selection process the superclass won't send a UIControlEventValueChanged event.
            // So we have to do this ourselves.
            [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSInteger previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    if ([[self class] isIOS7]) {
        // on iOS7 the segment is selected in touchesEnded
        if (previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

---

Swift 2.2 version, fixed the problem Grzegorz noticed.

```
class ReselectableSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    @IBInspectable var allowReselection: Bool = true

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex
        super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
        if allowReselection && previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self)
                if CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, touchLocation) {
                    self.sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Swift 3.0 changes the fix for this to look like the following:

```
class MyDeselectableSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let previousIndex = selectedSegmentIndex

        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        if previousIndex == selectedSegmentIndex {
            let touchLocation = touches.first!.location(in: self)

            if bounds.contains(touchLocation) {
                sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer aided me a 2nd time when iOS7 was released.  I should be able to upvote it again.

Comment: You can also encapsulate the deselecting code within this subclass by adding `self.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;` before `[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Comment: Problem with that solution is when you start touch on component and drag it outside component to cancel touch - it still deselects the item

Comment: Thats a really nice solution! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Here is a fix for a problem that when you try to cancel selection by starting tap on UISegmentControl and later you finish touch outside - it still does deselection.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
CGPoint viewPoint = [self convertPoint:locationPoint fromView:self];
if ([self pointInside:viewPoint withEvent:event]) {
    int oldValue = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    if (oldValue == self.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        [super setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `[self pointInside:withEvent]` uses the visible dimensions of the segmented control. If I use this and touch inside, then drag just a little outside before releasing, it leaves the segment light blue, like my finger is still down, and does not send the event. Is there a way to know the hitTest region for the control to see if the point is within it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the following (thank you [Grzegorz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21459772/347339) and [Matthias's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17652998/347339)):

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSInteger previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex;

    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGPoint viewPoint = [self convertPoint:locationPoint fromView:self];
    if ([self pointInside:viewPoint withEvent:event] && previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        self.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
}
```

I have made an open-source (MIT Licensed) class [STASegmentedControl](https://github.com/Stunner/STAControls/blob/master/STAControls/STAControls/SegmentedControl/STASegmentedControl.m) (supports iOS 7+), that has this functionality baked in (and more).

Answer (score 2):

In reference to the answer posted by @Matthias Bauch. I had to make little changes as per **Swift 2.2** in Xcode 7.3:

```
class ReselectableSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    @IBInspectable var allowReselection: Bool = true
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex
        super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
        if allowReselection && previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self)
                if CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, touchLocation) {
                    self.sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

swift **3.1** version posted by @Kushal Ashok

```
class ReselectableSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    @IBInspectable var allowReselection: Bool = true

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        if allowReselection && previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
                if bounds.contains(touchLocation) {
                    self.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution wich is independent from IOS Version. It's choosing the behaviour itself.

```
@interface CustomSegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl
@end




@implementation CustomSegmentedControl{


BOOL _touchBegan;
BOOL _reactOnTouchBegan;
}



- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    _touchBegan = YES;

    NSInteger previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if (_reactOnTouchBegan) {
        // before iOS7 the segment is selected in touchesBegan
        if (previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
    }
}


-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    _touchBegan = NO;

    NSInteger previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    if (!_reactOnTouchBegan) {
        CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
        CGPoint viewPoint = [self convertPoint:locationPoint fromView:self];
        if ([self pointInside:viewPoint withEvent:event]) {
            // on iOS7 the segment is selected in touchesEnded
            if (previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex) {
                [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            }
        }
    }
}


- (void)sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents {
    if(controlEvents == UIControlEventValueChanged){
        _reactOnTouchBegan = _touchBegan;
    }
    [super sendActionsForControlEvents:controlEvents];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful! Thank you! I wanted a little more control over the events for my project, so I adapted @Matthias's answer to send a custom "Value unchanged" event. I put an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/geoffhom/example-Same-Value-Segmented-Control).

I also incorporated @Grzegorz's fix so it behaves properly if the user drags her finger outside the segmented control.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to @Stunner, this is my contribution to achieve the goal. I changed something and added the property _previousSelectedSegmentIndex; in the @Stunner code the variable previousSelectedSegmentIndex was useless:

```
@implementation STASegmentedControl
{
    NSInteger _previousSelectedSegmentIndex;
}

- (void)setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)selectedSegmentIndex
{
    [super setSelectedSegmentIndex: selectedSegmentIndex];

    _previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGPoint viewPoint = [self convertPoint:locationPoint fromView:self];
    if (self.toggleableSegments) { // toggle selected segment on/off
        if ([self pointInside:viewPoint withEvent:event] && _previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            self.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
            [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
    }
    _previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
}
```