# Out of Bounds Error when Deselecting Segment

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uisegmentedcontrol

I am attempting to programmatically deselect a UISegmentedControl from within Xamarin whenever the user re-taps the selected segment. I have created an inherited class that will determine if this is required, but whenever I try to set `SelectedSegment` to -1, the application bombs out, throwing an out of bounds exception.

```
public class UIDeselectableSegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl
{
    private int previouslySelectedIndex = -1;

    private bool isIOS7
    {
        get
        {
            return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(7, 0);
        }
    }

    public UIDeselectableSegmentedControl()
    {
        this.ValueChanged += UIDeselectableSegmentedControl_ValueChanged;
    }

    void UIDeselectableSegmentedControl_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (previouslySelectedIndex == this.SelectedSegment)
        {
            this.SelectedSegment = -1;
        }
        previouslySelectedIndex = this.SelectedSegment;
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        int initialIndex = this.SelectedSegment;

        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

        //Pre-iOS7 Segment Changes are present in Touches Began
        if (!isIOS7) CheckSelectedSegment(initialIndex, this.SelectedSegment);

    }

    public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        int initialIndex = this.SelectedSegment;

        base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);

        //Post-iOS7 Segment Changes are present in Touches Ended
        if (isIOS7) CheckSelectedSegment(initialIndex, this.SelectedSegment);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compare the SelectedSegment with the Current Index value. If it is the same, raise the Value Changed event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Currently Selected Segment</param>
    private void CheckSelectedSegment(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
    {
        if (oldIndex == newIndex)
        {
            this.SendActionForControlEvents(UIControlEvent.ValueChanged);
        }
    }

}
```

If I change it to `this.SelectedSegment = 0` then the control will successfully force the SegementedControl to the first item whenever you re-tap another selected item, but if I have it to set it to `-1`, then it throws the following exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Is there a different way I should be deselecting the segment? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652773/how-to-deselect-a-segment-in-segmented-control-button-permanently-till-its-click) answer this is the correct way in Objective-C, and the Metadata comment on SelectedSegment indicates this is it correct:

```
//
// Summary:
//     The index of the selected segment.
//
// Remarks:
//     Set to -1 to turn off the currently selected segment. If MonoTouch.UIKit.UISegmentedControl.Momentary
//     == true the SelectedSegment property is ignored.
```

Answer (score 0):

In typical form, I think I've solved my own issue. I'm not sure *why* (perhaps someone can clarify this), but it seems to be something to do with trying to change the `SelectedSegment` within the `ValueChanged` event. Possibly some sort of mutation exception essentially.

I've reworked my code, so that the method called within TouchesEnded/Began just makes the change itself directly, rather than forcing ValueChanged to be called and changing it itself. In a way, that makes more sense, since ValueChanged is reacting to a change - it probably shouldn't be responsible for *making* the change:

```
public class UIDeselectableSegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl
{
    private bool isIOS7
    {
        get
        {
            return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(7, 0);
        }
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        int initialIndex = this.SelectedSegment;

        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

        //Pre-iOS7 Segment Changes are present in Touches Began
        if (!isIOS7) DeselectSegmentIfApplicable(initialIndex, this.SelectedSegment);

    }

    public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        int initialIndex = this.SelectedSegment;

        base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);

        //Post-iOS7 Segment Changes are present in Touches Ended
        if (isIOS7) DeselectSegmentIfApplicable(initialIndex, this.SelectedSegment);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compare the SelectedSegment with the Current Index value. If it is the same, raise the Deselect the Segment.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oldIndex">the previously selected segment</param>
    /// <param name="newIndex">The newly selected segment</param>
    private void DeselectSegmentIfApplicable(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
    {
        if (oldIndex == newIndex)
        {
            this.SelectedSegment = -1;
        }
    }
}
```