# UISegmentedControl unselect segment by pressing it again

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

How can one unselect a given segment in a UISegmented control, by pressing the same segment again?

E.g. Press segment 0, it becomes selected and remains highlighted.  Press segment 0 again and it becomes unselected and unhighlighted.

The control only fires UIControlEventValueChanged events.  Other events don't seem to work with it.

There is a property 'momentary' which when set to YES almost allows the above behavior, excepting that highlighting is only momentary.  When momentary=YES pressing the same segment twice results in two UIControlEventValueChanged events, but when momentary=NO only the first press of a given segment results in a UIControlEventValueChanged event being fired.  I.e. subsequent presses on the same segment will not fire the UIControlEventValueChanged event.

Comment: There will always a segment selected, you can't unselect all. Better create your segmentcontrol using UIButton.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to agree with @iphonic. If you have a good use case for this behavior, file an enhancement request - it does sound like a cool thing to be able to do - but as it stands, I think you are just trying to pervert the behavior of the segmented control, and you're not going to succeed.

Answer (score 10):

you can subclass UISegmentedControl:

**Swift 3**

```
class ReselectableSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex

        super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)

        if previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self)
                if CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, touchLocation) {
                    self.sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**Swift 4**

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex

    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

    if previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex {
        let touch = touches.first!
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        if bounds.contains(touchLocation) {
            self.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
 @IBAction func segmentChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == selectedSegmentIndex) {
        sender.selectedSegmentIndex =  UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
        selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
    }
    else {
        selectedSegmentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried half a dozen suggestions and this is the only one that worked.

Comment: Note: `if let touch = touches.first {` is overly cautious— `touches` always contains 1 or more `UITouch`es, so `let touch = touches.first!` will always suceed.  Otherwise, great answer.  Cheers

Comment: @protspace, Could you explain why we need to check if the touch is within the bounds of the view? Isn't that a given, since the event was sent to the view in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Not EXACTLY what you ask for but I was searching for a similar feature and decided on this.

Add doubleTap gesture to UISegmentedControl that sets the selectedSegmentIndex

When you initialize your UISegmentedControl.

```
let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action #selector(YourViewController.doubleTapToggle))
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
yourSegmentedControl.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
```

Function to deselect segment

```
@objc func doubleTapToggle () {
    yourSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = -1
    yourSegmentedControl.sendActions(for: valueChanged)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @protspace answer, a simpler way, without having to write anything in the `@IBAction`:

```
class DeselectableSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let previousSelectedSegmentIndex = selectedSegmentIndex

        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        if previousSelectedSegmentIndex == selectedSegmentIndex {
            let touch = touches.first!
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            if bounds.contains(touchLocation) {
                selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControl.noSegment
                sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

UISegmentedControl can be programmatically deselected with Swift using `@IBOutlet weak var mySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!` and `mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = -1`. As far as detecting the touch of the segment, I do not know. Hopefully someone else will have that answer.

Comment: See this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652773/how-to-deselect-a-segment-in-segmented-control-button-permanently-till-its-click)