# UISegmentedControl deselected is not recognised in code although it is visually

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a 5 segment segmentedControl which I've subclassed using the code from this post:

[How to deselect a segment in Segmented control button permanently till its clicked again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652773/how-to-deselect-a-segment-in-segmented-control-button-permanently-till-its-click?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

to allow the controller to be deselected when the selected segment is touched for a second time.

This works visually but when trying to assign a UserDefault it's just recognised as the segment that was touched twice.

I can't figure out what I can add to either the subclass code, or the viewController code to make this work.

Any help would be appreciated.

SUBCLASS CODE:

```
class mySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    @IBInspectable var allowReselection: Bool = true

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        if allowReselection && previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

                if bounds.contains(touchLocation) {
                    self.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
                    self.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

VIEWCONTROLLER CODE:

```
@IBOutlet weak var METDome_L: UISegmentedControl!
let key_METDome_L = "METDome_L"
var METD_L: String!

@IBAction func METDome_Lselect(_ sender: Any) {
    if METDome_L.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
        METD_L = "1"
        UserDefaults.standard.set(METD_L, forKey: key_METDome_L)
    }
    else if METDome_L.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{
        METD_L = "2"
        UserDefaults.standard.set(METD_L, forKey: key_METDome_L)
    }
    else if METDome_L.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{
        METD_L = "3"
        UserDefaults.standard.set(METD_L, forKey: key_METDome_L)
    }
    else if METDome_L.selectedSegmentIndex == 3{
        METD_L = "4"
        UserDefaults.standard.set(METD_L, forKey: key_METDome_L)
    }
    else if METDome_L.selectedSegmentIndex == 4{
        METD_L = "5"
        UserDefaults.standard.set(METD_L, forKey: key_METDome_L)
    }
    else{
        METD_L = "NONE"
        UserDefaults.standard.set(METD_L, forKey: key_METDome_L)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related but you can replace the **entire** code in  `METDome_Lselect` with one line: `UserDefaults.standard.set("\(sender.selectedSegmentIndex + 1)", forKey: key_METDome_L)`. The last `else` will never be executed anyway. By the way, this is not Javascript or PHP. Variable names are supposed to be *camelCased* rather than *snake_cased*.

Comment: Thanks @vadian! I knew there must be a way to shorten the code, but never even thought of doing it the way you said so that's really helpful.
However the else part is the code I really need to get working. I also tried `else if METDome_L.selectedSegmentIndex == UISegmentedControlNoSegment` however I guess that also will never be executed.
On the note of variable names, for the most part I have used _camelCased_ I just used the underscore to separate parts of the variable to make it easier to recognise as I'm fairly new to coding and I can easily get lost with the amount of code.

Comment: I doubt that the `IBAction` is triggered when the control is deselected programmatically. You could move the line to write `NONE` into the subclass

Comment: @vadian I had thought of that but I'm using this on multiple segmented controls so they would start to effect each other if I tried that. Unless I created a subclass for each segmented control, but that seems extremely inefficient.
Also I checked what happens on the second tap and it looks like programmatically the selection that it being tapped is just set for a second time.

Comment: Add a property `selectionKey` (or whatever appropriate) to the subclass and set it separately for each instance. Rather than using a `String` I would write an `Int` to `UserDefaults` without doing the math. Segment `1` (actually Segment `0`) is index `0` (almost all programming languages use zero-based indices)  and `UISegmentedControlNoSegment` represents `-1` anyway. That makes it very easy to restore the values.

Comment: @vadian I'm not entirely sure what you are saying to do here. I get the segment index values but I'm confused with why you would write an `Int` to `UserDefaults` and what you are asking for to do with the `selectionKey`. Would you be able to supply some example code?

Comment: I wrote an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you are subclassing the control you have to use that type to get the enhanced functionality.

```
@IBOutlet weak var METDome_L: MySegmentedControl! // class names start with a capital letter
```

Add a property `selectionKey` and save the state `UISegmentedControlNoSegment` (as `Int`) in `UserDefaults` when the control is deselected. A `fatal error` is thrown if the property is empty (it has to be set in the view controllers which use the subclass).

```
class MySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    @IBInspectable var allowReselection: Bool = true

    var selectionKey = ""

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.selectedSegmentIndex
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        if allowReselection && previousSelectedSegmentIndex == self.selectedSegmentIndex {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

                if bounds.contains(touchLocation) {
                    self.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
                    self.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
                    guard !selectionKey.isEmpty else { fatalError("selectionKey must not be empty")
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(UISegmentedControlNoSegment, forKey: selectionKey)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your view controller set the property `selectionKey` in `viewDidLoad` to the custom key and save the selected state of the control to `UserDefaults` in the `IBAction`. Do not any math. The first segment is segment 0 with index 0. Get used to zero-based indices. That makes it more convenient to restore the selected state.

```
@IBOutlet weak var METDome_L: MySegmentedControl!
let key_METDome_L = "METDome_L"

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    METDome_L.selectionKey = key_METDome_L
}

@IBAction func METDome_Lselect(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.selectedSegmentIndex, forKey: key_METDome_L)
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Did exactly what I needed! The only reason I was saving the `userDefaults` as _strings_ was because each segment is the number, and when I call it back on the next page it displays the number. But as you say, it's a lot more convenient to save them as _Int_ values and convert them later.